# How to define a global constant available everywhere in the application?

Tags: php, yii

How can I define an `UPLOAD_DIR` constant (or equivalent) so that I can use it everywhere?

I tried this as an application configuration parameter

```
'params'=>array(
            'upload_dir'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/uploads/',
),
```

but `Yii::app()->baseUrl` cannott be used inside the config file.

Comment: You're mixing directories and URL paths here. Best practice is to define both of them. 
Paths can also be created with aliases, but that has to be a convention of yours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this inside `index.php`, after the call to `Yii::createApplication` and before `Yii::app()->run()`:

```
define ('UPLOAD_DIR', Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/uploads/');
```

You would then use it just like any other PHP constant, e.g. `echo UPLOAD_DIR`.

**Edit:** When I said after `createApplication` and before `run`, I meant exactly that (also, not that there is both a `createWebApplication` and a `createApplication`, which is a more generalized version of the former).

So if you currently have

```
Yii::createWebApplication(...)->run();
```

you have to split it into

```
Yii::createWebApplication(...);
define ('UPLOAD_DIR', Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/uploads/');
Yii::app()->run();
```

---

Another option would be to just add another property to your application class. For example, if you have a `class MyApplication` inside your `protected/components` directory then you can simply do this:

```
class MyApplication extends CWebApplication {
    // ...other code...
    public function getUploadDir() {
        return $this->baseUrl.'/images/uploads/';
    }
}
```

You would then access this as `Yii::app()->uploadDir`.

Comment: define() in index file doesn't work i tried it after and before Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Comment: inside my protected/components there is only UserIdentity.php and Controller.php

Comment: @safiot: See the edit. The application class is inside `/protected/components` *if you have one*; otherwise you 'll need to create it yourself *and* you will need to use `createApplication` instead of `createWebApplication`.